# this keyword not working in servlet

Tags: java, servlets, this

In the following servlet i want to add content type and character set encoding.

```
  public class FBOAuth extends HttpServlet {
  public void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
     PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
     this.response.setContentType("application/json");
     this.response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
...
```

I compile this servlet using following command.

```
$ javac -classpath json.jar FBOAuth.java
```

### ERROR

```
FBOAuth.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
this.response.setContentType("application/json");
    ^
symbol: variable response
FBOAuth.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
this.response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    ^
 symbol: variable response
 2 errors
```

Comment: Man, you need to learn Java. Start with the java tutorial. Asking questions in SO each time you run in a compile time error won't help you progress.

Answer (score 7):

Remove `this.` before `response`. They're parametres, not class variables.

Answer (score 0):

Remove **this** keyword from the code and it will work. Since HTTPServletRequest and HttpServletResponse object will work for the current request only since it is stateless protocol and it will work on the current object only.
This keyword is used only for your member variables and member functions not for the inbuilt objects since both these objects(request,response) comes implicitly.